# Merge two sorted lists and preserve order

Tags: python, algorithm

Given two lists e.g.

```
l1 = ["A","D","B","C"]
l2 = ["X","A","Y","B"]
```

I want the result to preserve the order given by both input lists i.e.

```
["X","A","D","Y","B","C"]
```

The result is not unique as "D" and "Y" could also be switched (but if it is not clear lexicographic order should handle the conflict)
Also if I had smth. like

```
l1 = ["B","A"]
l2 = ["X","A","Y","B"]
```

positions of either B or A should be treated interchangeably (i.e. no unique order can be constructed and the order of B< A and B> A should be treated as A=B) which would lead to accepted results

```
["X","A","Y","B"]
```

(preferably as it is in deterministic lexicographic order of A and B) or

```
["X","B","Y","A"]
```

Put in another way I want the combination of lists to preserve the order where unique and where it's not, the result should be deterministic e.g. according to lexicographic ordering.

Is there a library for python that accomplishes that or would I have to implement it on my own?
I looked at OrderedDict and OrderedSet but both do not handle the merge as I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use to use [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). If you don't want to implement the algorithm from scratch, you can use the [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) Python package:

```
from itertools import chain
from networkx import DiGraph, topological_sort

l1 = ["A", "D", "B", "C"]
l2 = ["X", "A", "Y", "B"]

# Build the graph
G = DiGraph(chain(zip(l1[:-1], l1[1:]), zip(l2[:-1], l2[1:])))

# Return a list of nodes in topological sort order
result = list(topological_sort(G))

# result: ['X', 'A', 'Y', 'D', 'B', 'C']
```

Basically, you build a graph where every directed edge from vertex u to vertex v implies that u comes before v in the ordering. In this specific example, "A" comes before "D", "D" comes before "B" etc:

```
>>> G.edges
[('A', 'D'), ('A', 'Y'), ('D', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('X', 'A'), ('Y', 'B')]
```

Comment: Thanks, I like that. I can imagine by finding the cycles e.g if l2 = ["X","B","Y","A"] I could delete the edge between B->A and just leave A->B. I will try that out. Runtime for your approach would be O((n+l)+m) right w/o deleting the cycles? First answer might be O(n*l)? n=len(l1), l=len(l2), m=edges. Though runtime is not yet an issue for me.

Comment: @user3456323 correct! Well, you need to define a precise strategy to get rid of cycles. Once you have it I can help you with getting rid of them. Also, please upvote my answer if you think it is useful

Comment: I used your approach and removed the cycles by removing the last edge in cycles that are found:   while True:
        try:
            edge = find_cycle(G, orientation='original')[-1]
            G.remove_edge(edge[0],edge[1])
        except:
            break

Comment: Found one minor corner case when there is only one node in either of the lists. So the complete solution should include the following tests:
    if len(l1)==1:
        l1 = [l1[0],l1[0]]

    if len(l2)==1:
        l2 = [l2[0],l2[0]]

    G = DiGraph(chain(zip(l1[:-1], l1[1:]), zip(l2[:-1], l2[1:])))